# VBA Chart Manipulation Slow

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I wrote some Excel VBA code that generates a scatterplot and changes a few properties of the chart. (Code is below for reference.)  The code moves slowly through tasks like deleting the chart legend, removing horizontal/vertical gridlines, and changing the X and Y series.  Excel's timer gives me the following duration for each task:

```
insert scatterplot: 0.01171875 
delete series: 0 
plot x vs y: 0.55859375 
delete legend: 0.5703125 
delete chart title: 0.66015625 
remove grid: 1.3046875 
format axes: 0 
overall: 3.11328125
```

Removing the grid, changing the title, plotting the X and Y series, and deleting the legend seem to take a long time.  I've googled for alternative ways to write the code, but haven't been able to find anything useful.  The code works entirely as expected, except for the slow speed.  Any ideas as to what's causing the bad performance, and how I can speed this up?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've already turned off screen updating while working with the chart.  The chart is generated/formatted while a userform is open, if that makes any difference.

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
With ActiveChart
    'Delete all series currently in plot
    Do While .FullSeriesCollection.Count > 0
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop

    'Plot Actual (Y) vs. Inverse Distribution (X)
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & tempSheetName & "!$C:$C"
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & tempSheetName & "!$A:$A"

    'Delete legend
    .Legend.Delete

    'Delete chart title
    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleNone)

    'Remove gridlines
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone)
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesNone)

    'Format axes
    Dim xAxis As Axis, yAxis As Axis
    Set xAxis = .Axes(xlCategory)
    Set yAxis = .Axes(xlValue)

    With yAxis
        'Title y axis "actual"
        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Caption = "Actual"

        'Add tick marks
        .MajorTickMark = xlOutside
    End With

    With xAxis
        'Title x axis by dist type
        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Caption = dist.getDistType

        'Add tick marks
        .MajorTickMark = xlOutside
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the data and machine specifics it can be hard to say why this is slow, although here are some alternatives to some of the code you have.

The first and foremost thing I'd change is *not* to Activate the chart.  If you are creating the chart through code, do so but set it to a variable, eg `Set wcChart = ThisWorkbook.Charts.Add`.  Then change `With ActiveChart` to `With wcChart`.

Also, delete the `FullSeriesCollection` and then delete the chart title, remove the gridlines and change the axes before filling up the new data.  The chart manipulation should be quicker with less data in the chart.  Be careful here though because changing aspects of the chart in different orders *can* produce different outputs (as an example the layout of a legend).

You fill the new `FullSeriesCollection` with the entire columns of A and C, specify the exact range of the data rather than the whole column.

Other changes to try, I'm not saying these will work but they are worth a shot if you haven't tried.  Instead of checking for a `FullSeriesCollection` each time:

```
Do While .FullSeriesCollection.Count > 0
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
Loop
```

The following *may* be quicker:

```
For ii = .FullSeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
    .FullSeriesCollection(ii).Delete
Next ii
```

Also, instead of `.SetElement` for the Chart title and Gridlines I use the following:

```
'You have to set the title to 'True' before it'll work with 'False'.  Go figure.
.HasTitle = True
.HasTitle = False

.HasMajorGridlines = False
.HasMinorGridlines = False
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions -- I've been able to cut the entire process down to 0.5 seconds from the previous 3 seconds.  It seems that the key suggestion here was to plot the X and Y series last, and manipulate the chart with no data in the chart.

The runtime now, for reference:

`insert scatterplot: 0.05078125
delete series: 0
delete legend: 0
delete chart title: 0
format axes: 0
plot x vs y: 0.5234375
overall: 0.578125`

Comment: Also -- as far as removing the chart title, I was able to use `.HasTitle = False` without first setting to true and had no problems.  It should also be noted that `.HasMajorGridlines` and `.HasMinorGridlines` are properties of an `Axis` rather than a `Chart`.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked, you must have a reasonable amount of data points for it to slow down.  You'll need `.HasTitle = False/True` for backward compatibility with at least 2007 (maybe 2010?).  Fair enough with the gridlines.